# How to redirect to other jsp without query String?

Tags: struts2

How to redirect to other jsp without using query string (same like post method) in url in struts framework.

Comment: Use redirect to the action

Comment: Redirect from where? What are you trying to do?

Comment: from one jsp page to another jsp page

Comment: but i'm using redirecting page using <a> tag.

Comment: But use form if you want post method.